# Used to be made of tin

Tags: riddle

> Started from a pipe
>
> Used to be made of tin or paper
>
> Millions use me
>
> You started by saying things to me
>
> Now you do a lot more and still want more

What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A telephone

Started from a pipe

> Early distance communications (through a submarine, for instance) used to be speaking through pipes

Used to be made of tin or paper

> Tin can telephones are still fun crafts to do with kids

Millions use me

> There's a few people in the world that have a phone

You started by saying things to me

> Phones used to be just for talking

Now you do a lot more and still want more

> Cell phones are for much more than talking now